# Why this code is working fine on my system and throwing EmptyStackException in HackersRank

Tags: java

There is a counting valley problem in https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem
I know my is not the best solution but it works fine on my system with the sample testcases but seems to fail on hackersRank with the same test case.This throws emptyStack exception on "climbStack.peek()"
I tried the following code with J9 compiler but J7 style as hackerrank only supports j7

```
// Complete the countingValleys function below.
static int countingValleys(int n, String s)
{
    Stack<String> climbStack = new Stack<String>();
    boolean mClimb = false;
    int valleyCount=0;
    String[] trek = s.split("");

    for(int i =0 ; i < trek.length; i++)
    {
        if(climbStack.empty() && trek[i].equals("U"))
        {
            mClimb = true;
            climbStack.push(trek[i]);
            continue;
        }
        else if(climbStack.empty() && trek[i].equals("D"))
        {
            mClimb = false;
            climbStack.push(trek[i]);
            continue;
        }

        if(climbStack.peek().equals(trek[i]))
        {
            climbStack.push(trek[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            climbStack.pop();
            if(climbStack.empty() && mClimb == false && i <= n)
            {
                valleyCount++;
            }
        }

    }
    return valleyCount;

}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    String s = scanner.nextLine();

    int result = countingValleys(n, s);

    System.out.println(result);

    scanner.close();
}
```

Input
8
UDDDUDUU

Result 1

Comment: Maybe the input you receive contains an unexpected character. Your code would throw EmptyStackException in that case.

Comment: This is the input they provide and I too use the same from my commandline, https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/22936/input00.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1550138453&Signature=wHwrr9iCpNHdB3wMN%2BjskB4nrn0%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Can't you obtain the output of the program execution on HackerRank? If so, you can add ant System.out.println in order to trace, e.g., the content of the stack before each call to `peek` method...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that method `split()` works differently in J7 than in J9. If your input is a string of 'U' and 'D' characters only and you need to separate them into individual letters then I suggest method `toCharArray()` instead of `split()` which will give you a `char[]` of length 8 - using the sample input you posted, and method `toCharArray()` exists since the very early Java releases.